Extract data from api to data frame in R
First, I am very new to api stuff, so maybe the solution is simple.
I have access to the Danish Erhvervsstyrelsen's api for enterprise data (CVR information from virk.dk). They use elastic.
The documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html
In Danish: https://assets.ctfassets.net/kunz2thx8mib/3c60K4hOmJgAFDiuCKWAhH/f5401ed983649a411506d7acd02264d0/kom_godt_igang_med_elasticsearch.v6.8.16.pdf
Mapping (I don't know what this is): http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/_mapping
I know how to connect to the api, but I don' know how to go from the very nested json-data to an R data frame.
Here's my code:
# Library
library(httr)

# Connecting
url <- GET("http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/virksomhed/_search",
       authenticate("user_name",
                    "password"))

# Checking if the connection was succesfull (it is)
url$status_code
[1] 200 

From here I have tried some different stuff. Again I know nothing about this api stuff, I just need the data for my analysis.
# Trying the jsonlite package
url_char <- rawToChar(url$content)
json_data<- fromJSON(url_char)

json_data
$took
[1] 14

$timed_out
[1] FALSE

$`_shards`
$`_shards`$total
[1] 6

$`_shards`$successful
[1] 6

$`_shards`$skipped
[1] 0

$`_shards`$failed
[1] 0


$hits
$hits$total
[1] 2115475

$hits$max_score
[1] 1

$hits$hits

# Trying to make it into a data.frame
data_raw <- do.call("rbind",
                lapply(json_data, as.data.frame))
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
antal argumentkolonner svarer ikke overens

I think that it doesn't work might be because my data is more nested.
Another method I've tried:
# Extracting in json 
cont_raw <- content(url)

# Unlisting
data_raw <- enframe(unlist(cont_raw)) 

# How many cols?
rgx_split <- "\\."
n_cols_max <- data_raw %>%
                 pull(name) %>% 
                 str_split(rgx_split) %>% 
                 map_dbl(~length(.)) %>% 
                 max()
n_cols_max
[1] 11

# Separating
nms_sep <- paste0("name", 1:n_cols_max)
data_sep <- data_raw %>% 
               separate(name, 
                        into = nms_sep, 
                        sep = rgx_split, 
                        fill = "right")

And this is when I noticed that I only get 10 enterprises ("cvr-numbers"). I am expecting thousands, maybe even more than 100.000.
I noticed in my cont_raw that the list hits has a list hits and this list has 10 lists. Each one a list of 5. Inside each of the 10 elements of cont_raw$hits$hits there is a list called _source. This is a list of 1, and it has the list Vrvirksomhed (virksomhed means enterprise in Danish). The Vrvirksomhed list is a list of 44. Some of these elements are lists too, but not all.
It seems like the cont_raw consist of the the data for those 10 enterprises (the first 10 lists = one for each of the enterprises).
This is where I am very confused since I have access to all of the data.
I have also tried rrapply with melt, and it gives me the same as cont_raw, just not as long.
I am sorry if I'm not clear, please let me know if you need more info to help me out.

You're going to have to either: a) provide username and password in order to successfully authenticate to the api or b) some sample data with dput so we can see the structure of the data returned by the api.

I find it useful to explore the content more visually first, using listviewer::jsonedit(content(url, as = "text")) and also headers(url); generally you want to use functions rather than $ to access httr results. Likely your results are returned as 'pages', with say 10 results per page, and you need to make several requests and retrieve multiple pages, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size. Once you figure it out, you would want to query for many more (e.g., 1000) hits at a time.
